# Apache2 will only serve small files

Tags: apache

I just know this is one of those questions where the solution should have been obvious and I'm going to feel like an idiot but I'm stuck.

I've set up a basic apache2 web sever under openSUSE Leap 15.1 on my LAN with a single virtual host (for the moment).

If I create a simple html file of 255 bytes or less a browser on another workstation picks it up without problem. If the file gets to anything larger than 255 bytes apache doesn't serve it. The GET request shows up on the server but nothing shows in Firefox, Konqueror at least gives me a 1b Object not found error.

I should say that running a browser on the server itself shows all these files perfectly well should I use 127.0.0.1, localhost or the server name in the URL.

Is this an Apache2 directive I've missed or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

After setting the LogLevel to trace1 and then hunting around on the web I came across what appears to be the solution. Set the Apache directive ...

`EnableSendfile Off`

Apparently Apache is compiled with this set to On and the kernel sendfile doesn't do the job. Not a detailed explanation I know but I haven't followed this all the way through - I just needed to get Apache working!